# How TV can show ORIGINAL laptops screen using HDMI?

Tags: hdmi

I connected my TV and laptop using HDMI cable. In the terminal I typed `xrandr` command. The Ubuntu Desktop GUI appeared on the TV screen.

Based on my understanding, the screen shown on the TV is the second laptops panel. When I go to `Settings - Screen Display`, I see 2 screens:

1. Built-in Display;
2. Sony 46" (a screen to the right)

If I turn the `Sony 46` screen off in the settings, the screen on the TV also turns off. What I want is my TV to show the first `Build-in Display` screen.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

As it is written, what you want to do exactly is unclear.

If I understand correctly, you just need to check the "mirror displays" option.

Go Settings > displays:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you want to mirror your displays

To do that, open Settings > Display, and just tick **Mirror Displays** option.

If you want to do that in terminal, run the following command:

```
xrandr --output builtindisplayname --same-as 2nddisplayname
```

Now it should work